# PostgreSQL regex query to identify phone number translated to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am attempting to translate a regex in a PostgreSQL query to do the same thing in SQL Server. The query in PostgreSQL is using '+?1?[(]?([0-9]{3})?[)]?[- .]?[0-9]{3}[- .]?[0-9]{4}'. Which is designed to identify phone numbers in a string.

```
 SELECT '7178083687' AS VALUE,
    CASE
        WHEN '7178083687' ~ '\+?1?[(]?[0-9]{0,3}[)]?[- .]?[0-9]{3}[- .]?[0-9]{4}' 
        THEN 'PHONE'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
        END AS VALUE_TYPE
```

The above query in PostgreSQL yields what I'd expect and classifies the VALUE as the 'PHONE' VALUE TYPE. I translated the above to `'\+*1*[(]*[0-9]^3[)]*(-|,| )*[0-9]^3(-|,| )*[0-9]^4'` in SQL Server expecting the same result. However, I am hitting the ELSE condition.

```
SELECT '7178083687' AS VALUE,
    CASE
        WHEN '7178083687' LIKE '\+*1*[(]*[0-9]^3[)]*[- .]*[0-9]^3[- .]*[0-9]^4' 
        THEN 'PHONE'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
        END AS VALUE_TYPE
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support real (complete) regular expressions.

Comment: Are your phone numbers always in the format of 10 digits? It's usually best to sanitize data that you insert to the database and format the data you pull from it in your program.

Comment: They are 10 or 11 if there's a leading 1.

Comment: @Nemo if they're sanitized beforehand (to be only numbers), you can use `IIF(((@v LIKE '1%' AND LEN(@v) = 11) OR LEN(@v) = 10),'PHONE','UNKNOWN')`. You can also make it a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) if you want so that that information isn't stored, but is available with a quick calculation each time you pull data (without you having to specify the `iif` chunk of code it in each `select` statement).

Comment: @ctwheels, thanks. I was trying to handle multiple cases. I didn’t explain that earlier... sometimes with a leading 1, sometimes with parenthesis, sometimes with dashes or spaces, etc... I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions?view=sql-server-ver15 perhaps this’ll help.